# What instruction sets are in the Piledriver architecture that are not in Bulldozer?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I write quite a bit of code in 64-bit x86_64 assembly language, and I am about to begin another large function library to provide all conventional bitwise, shift, logical, arithmetic, math operators and functions for `s0128`, `s0256`, `s0512`, `s1024` signed integer types and `f0128`, `f0256`, `f0512`, `f1024` floating-point types.

I have AMD `FX-8150` (bulldozer) CPUs in both my computers (ubuntu64 and win7-64).  After reviewing the operations my code needs to perform, I find a great number of recent bit manipulation instructions will be extremely helpful.

However, when I read various documents, including the official AMD documents on their website, I find endless contradictions about whether certain instructions and instruction sets are supported by bulldozer CPUs (`FX-8150`) and/or piledriver (`FX-8350`).  The confusion is especially common with regard to the various recent bit manipulation instructions and instruction sets, and the `FMA3` and `FMA4` instruction sets.

I know some of the AMD documents are wrong, because I've been programming with `FMA3` and `FMA4` instructions on my `FX-8150` and they work just fine, while the AMD document comparing bulldozer and piledriver contradict this.

Given that ALL sources of documentation I can find appear to be wrong to some degree about this issue, does anyone out there know which instructions and/or instruction sets work on piledriver (`FX-8350`) but not bulldozer (`FX-8150`)?

Since my problem is the validity of documentation out there, please don't just point me at some document **unless you know for sure it is correct**.  The best answers would come from programmers who have tested these instructions and instruction sets on their bulldozer [and piledriver] CPUs.

Comment: "because I've been programming with FMA3 and FMA4 instructions on my FX-8150 and they work just fine" - I doubt it. Are you sure you are using FMA3 on Bulldozer? Bulldozer does not have FMA3.

Comment: About FMA3.  Well, I remember programming with them, but when I realized FMA4 were available, I switched over.  The FMA4 instructions are a lot more efficient for my purposes, because I didn't have to write over any operand.  Plus, they're about 1000x easier to understand when programming.  I'll go find a place where an FMA3 should work and see what happens.

Comment: @Mystical:  Oh, by the way, tell me what you see on page 2 of the following AMD document: http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/New-Bulldozer-and-Piledriver-Instructions.pdf

Comment: @Hans:  See previous comment (the AMD document).  Frankly, I'm not sure I believe the CPUID on this issue.  If nobody can definitively straighten me out, I'll go write some assembly and test every single one of the instructions myself, by hand (step through with debugger) to see what actually in fact works.  I really didn't want to go to all this effort, but looks like I might have to.  The various documentation disagrees so badly with each other, why should I believe the CPUID?  Seems like nobody knows what's going on here.

Comment: First discovery.  Well, I guess my memory is indeed defective.  When I tried to execute an `FMA3` instruction, that generated a `SIGILL` (illegal instruction), while `FMA4` instructions work fine (and indeed, I have dozens of `FMA4` instructions in my code).  Of course if you look at the AMD document I gave a link to above, it claims the bulldozer CAN execute `FMA3` instructions (wrong), but CANNOT execute `FMA4` instructions (wrong).  Now onto bit-oriented instructions.

Comment: Next discovery.  The newer bit instructions don't work in my bulldozer (`FX-8150`).  After laborious checks of the various `CPUID` bits, they seem mostly accurate (but a royal pain to understand).  One strange one is a `FMA` bit (that contains false in my bulldozer `FX-8150`) while it does execute `FMA4` but not `FMA3` instructions.  But I did find another `FMA` bit in the second set (with the `0x80000000` prefix) that's set to 1.  Overall, `CPUID` does seem fairly reliable, while the documentation for bulldozer out there in the world is massively inconsistent and largely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already figured, the official [AMD release document](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/New-Bulldozer-and-Piledriver-Instructions.pdf) (page 2) is indeed misleading. Specifically, the first line in this table **is wrong**:
[image: supported instructions (wrong)]

**Bulldozer** supports FMA4, but **not FMA3.**

For completeness, the Piledriver instructions not present in Bulldozer are [`BMI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets), [`TBM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#TBM), [`F16C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F16C) (previously named CVT16) and [`FMA3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) <sup>([2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add))</sup>.

These should provide confirmation about FMA3 not being present in Bulldozer. But in addition, you can trust [the GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html). Architectures are named `bdver1` and `bdver2` for Bulldozer and Piledriver respectively.

Even more, you can trust the [cpuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) return value. For convenience I am reproducing screenshots here for Zambezi and Vishera (the desktop parts):

[image: Zambezi and Vishera cores (screenshots from Aida64)]
Source: [CPUID Dump List](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/)

Note that `cpuid` uses simply `fma` to designate both the FMA3 and FMA4 support. GCC follows the same semantics. From the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) you can deduce that this is because the `FMA4` variant was actually implemented *before* FMA3 (so the previously defined `fma4` identifier couldn't simply be dropped or it would break existing applications).